# Launch an App by key press or a combination of key press - Window phone 8.1, iphone, Android

Tags: android, iphone, windows-phone-8.1, screenshot

I am planning to build an app which needs a screenshot. My requirement is to launch the app when the designated key presses are executed. (i.e. like volume up+lock key for taking screen shot in windows phone). My app will then launch automatically for further processing of that image. Is it possible to build or is there any work around for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt if this allowed in Windows OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to build such app for Windows Phone.

1. Even if an app is running it can't get access to hardware keys except BackKey.
2. App can't run in the backgroud. After user leaves app it goes suspend and only couple of BackgroundTask can be launched to run in background at that moment.

**EDIT**

To be clear your app on Windows Phone 8.1 can be done but it'll work like following:

1. User takes screenshot, goes to gallery and choosing to share it.
2. Your app must declare that it can receive image (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871367.aspx)
3. User see your app in share list, choose it and than your app gets screenshot and may start to work with it.

Comment: Is there any workaround to meet my requirement? Like URIs to open apps.

Comment: You can share content between apps but I don't think it'll help you. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thunbrynt/archive/2014/04/16/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-contracts.aspx

Comment: @Ganesh.G, I updated my answer to get you an idea how your app can work on WP8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on what @khamitimur has posted. You will be able to only list down the third party apps installed within your `Windows Phone` device programmatically but not to launch them using any hardware parts of the device.

P.s : The developers have not yet been given any access or API to hardware parts in order to trigger events from those.